# How access to DOM in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor application, news aggregator.
Mongo DB structure:

```
{_id: channelId, title: channelTitle, pubDate: channelPubdate, items: [{title: newsTitle, desc: newsDescription, link: newsLink, pubDate: Date, clicks: 0}, {}, {} ...] }

{_id: channelId, title: channelTitle, pubDate: channelPubdate, items: [{title: newsTitle, desc: newsDescription, link: newsLink, pubDate: Date, clicks: 0}, {}, {} ...] }
```

... etc

Template:

```
<template name="newsItems">
{{#each itemsList}}
    {{#each this.items}}
        <article class="news-body-custom" onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
            <div class="news-content-left">
                <h2 class="news-header-custom">{{this.title}}</h2>
                <time class="time-custom">{{dateTranslate this.pubDate}}</time>
                <p class="news-content-custom">{{{this.description}}}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="clicks">{{this.clicks}}</div>
        </article>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

events handler:

```
    Template.newsItems.events({
    "click .news-body-custom": function(e) {
        var iframe = document.getElementsByName("news-iframe")[0];
        iframe.src = this.link;

        var target = e.target;

        while (target.className !== "news-body-custom") {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }

        var clicks = target.getElementsByClassName("clicks")[0];
        clicks.innerHTML = +clicks.innerHTML + 1;
debugger;
        News.update({ _id: Session.get("channelId"), items: { $elemMatch: { link: this.link }}}, {$inc: {clicks: 1 }});
    }
});
```

I have two questions:

1. How I can access to DOM structure (template) in this events handler? I solved the problem using native JS - find target and after that find  element associated with target. I think this is not elegant. Is exist Meteor way?
2. I need save clicks on  in Mongo by incrementing this field. How I can do this? I try this News.update({ _id: Session.get("channelId"), items: { $elemMatch: { link: this.link }}}, { $inc: {clicks: 1 }}); but this is not work.

Thank you and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the template event functions give you both an event and a template object to work with:

```
Template.newsItems.events({
  "click .news-body-custom": function(e, t) {
    iframe = t.$.find('news-iframe')[0];
    iframe.src = this.link;

    var target = e.target;

    while (target.className !== "news-body-custom") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    var clicks = target.getElementsByClassName("clicks")[0];
    clicks.innerHTML = +clicks.innerHTML + 1;
    debugger;
    News.update({ _id: Session.get("channelId"), items: { $elemMatch: { link: this.link }}}, {$set: {"items.$": {$inc: {clicks: 1 }}}});
  }
});
```

You also want to make sure that you look at the $ positional updater in Mongo: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/.

Answer (score 1):

1.
The approach I use is

```
'csubmit form':function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(e.target).find('[name=test]');//something like that
}
```

2. Clicks won't append because your find return whole News, not just the array with clicks, IMO you should make another collection to hold those items like:

`{_id: channelId, title: channelTitle, pubDate: channelPubdate, items:[id1, id2, id3]}`

```
{{#each news}}
   {{#each Item}}

   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

and helper(made it quick, prolly there's better way to do it)

```
Item: function(){
  var array=[];
  for(var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++)
     array.append(Items.find({_id:this.items[0]})) 
  return array;
}
```

Then when iterating through each item do something like:

```
'click button': function(){
       Items.update({_id:this._id},{$inc:{clicks:1}});
}
```

Comment: While I agree that a refactor into another collection makes sense, my answer below actually covers how to do what the question asked. The event functions give you a template object for finding things, and you can use the positional operator to update the right part of the element in Mongo.